# Can't retrieve get variables in Laravel

Tags: php, http, laravel-5

I have the following in my routes.php:

```
Route::controller('hello', 'HelloController');
```

And I have the following in my HelloController.php:

```
use Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function getIndex(Request $request) 
{
    echo "hi";
    $param = $request->input('param');
    echo $param;
}
```

When I go to my URL `/hello?param=testparam` nothing is outputed for the `$param` value.  Any ideas?

**Update**
When I enter this in my URL: `index.php/hello?param=testparam`. It works fine. This leads me to believe it has something to do with pretty URLs.

Comment: are you getting any error ? Did you try doing $param = $request->param;

Comment: @zlen I am calling lluminate\Http\Request and still is null.

Comment: @KhanShahrukh No Error and I tried that as well.

Comment: Ok, as I see, you are not calling the function. Do that : Route::controller('hello', 'HelloController@getIndex');

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Did you try removing  `use Input;` you have access to `input` already using `Illuminate\Http\Request`..

Comment: I've tried all suggestions and nothing works.  The one thing I tried which made it work was I used index.php in my URL.  I'm not sure if the pretty URL declaration in my http.conf is causing this.  But adding index.php in my URL grabbed the GET variables. Hopefully that helps someone understand why this is occuring.  Id still like to have pretty URLS.

Comment: @saadel I removed use Input; but same issue.

Comment: @KingKongFrog, I am sorry posting some thing wrong just before, I was so tired, and it is deleted now. I have just tested your code it should works out of the box. It is bit tricky to say what it could be

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. I did this:

```
url('/hello/?param=testparam')
```

Adding a slash between worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment above, and after tests, you missed including the call to the function  `getIndex`.

You have to do that:

```
Route::controller('hello', 'HelloController@getIndex');
```

Comment: It seems that it's the one by default: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#implicit-controllers