# Unable to retrieve GET parameters using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a Laravel project and am trying to get GET parameters from a controller. Requesting a page with `?date={value}` should return `value` as follows:

```
public function getIndex(Request $request) {
    return $request->input("date");
}
```

This does not work though. POST requests work as they should. I am using nginx through cloudflare. I tried making a plain PHP file with

```
echo $_GET["date"];
```

which works fine.

Comment: Just to be clear, this parameter that you want is been passed as a query string?

Comment: @Victor Yes, that is correct

Comment: What version of laravel are you using? 4.2, 5.0 or 5.1? What does your route that call that Method looks like? See if [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744825/laravel-queries-strings) helps you.

Comment: @Victor I am using version 5.0. `Input::get("date")` does not work either. In routes.php I have `Route::controller('page', 'PageController');`.

Comment: is this a copy of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923484/cant-retrieve-get-variables-in-laravel/31927415#31927415 it is very identical

Comment: @maytham None of the answers worked for me

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found my problem. In the nginx configuration for the site (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`), I had

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?;
}
```

which should be

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Fixed, restarted, now it works.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was in `.htaccess` file after remove `index.php` from `url` , just add this simple code in `.htaccess`  file  :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe getIndex() and Request $request dont work with Route::controller. Use a get('/my-route'), It's more flexible.

Comment: Another page uses an explicit `Route::get('page', 'PageController@getIndex');`, but GET requests don't work there either.

Comment: You created another public function with the same param, works? (Change the function name and test)