# Laravel 8 pagination return the same data (offset is ignored - it is always zero)

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

SOLVED. My nginx configuration was wrong and now [it is fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925992/unable-to-retrieve-get-parameters-using-laravel/31944462#31944462).

I have code like this in controller:

```
$MyItems = App\Models\MyItems::paginate(10);
```

On URL `https://example.com/my-item` it will execute SQL:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▶]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `teams` order by `name` asc limit 10 offset 0"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 0.33
  ]
]
```

On URL `https://example.com/my-item?page=3` it will be the **same SQL** and the same data in respond. For some reason `offset` is always "0". Where did I turn wrong?

Comment: This is really strange... try checking if you are getting the `page` query parameter, maybe you have a problem there so it is not sending `?page=123` to the server so Laravel only sees like you are on first page all the time (this happened to me in a project where I was not able to configure CDN, so person who did it, did it wrong...)

Comment: Yes, you are right. It turns out it is not about pagination but about routing. `$_GET` array is empty on every single page but the `/`. I didn't find solution yet, but you already helped me a lot.

Comment: No problem, if you are using a CDN have a look at it ! If not, I am really as confused as you are.

Answer (score 0):

Since `App\Models\MyItems` is a class, it should be using [scope resolution](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) `::`

```php
$MyItems = App\Models\MyItems::paginate(10);
```

When the left part is an object instance, you use `->`.  Otherwise, you use `::`

Comment: That is just a typo I made while simplifying the question, sorry.

Comment: Then the URL parameters might not be populated correctly. Try dumping `$request->page` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be like this

```
$MyItems = App\Models\MyItems::paginate(10);
```

Comment: That is just a typo I made while simplifying the question, sorry.

Comment: you mean this does not worked for you

Comment: yep, sorry i confused you